# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSException

Tags: java, exception

Currently, I am a novice programmer. I am building a library for encryption with OpenSSL. In that Libray, I have two external libraries: `bcprov-jdk15on-1.67.jar` and `bcpkix-jdk15on-1.67.jar`.  After that, I import the library into my new project for the purpose of testing Encryption and Decryption, but I found an error like this...
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSException.`
It seems like my new project can not refer to those classes belongs to the external library I have included. How can I export my library as a jar and included those external libraries? I would be much appreciated for your help. Thank you.

This is the library I have built and I added two external libraries.

[image: This is the library I have built and I added two external libraries]

I have imported my library into my testing project.

[image: I have imported my library into my testing project]

When I called the function from my library, it shows this error. It seems like it can't load those classes.

[image: When I called the function from my library, it shows this error. It seems like it can't load those classes.]

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly import the libraries?

Comment: @Alexander, yes I correctly imported the library to the new project. 
It seem like when I export the library, those external libraries didn't come with the jar file.